# axios problem with sending all requests in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an array of items in the local storage and i want to send them all at once to my API
problem is when I send them all the API tells me it got all the requests but this loop doesnt remove them from the local storage its like it didn't get a response or something

```js
let local_items = localStorage.getItem("items")
local_items = JSON.parse(local_items)
loadingToast("Syncing items")
for (let i = 0; i < local_items.length; i++) {
  axios.post('/items', {
    item: local_items[i],
    shop: '1',
    employee: '1'
  }, config).then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      local_items.splice(i, 1)
      //it counts down 2 or 3 times then gets stuck on a number
      alert("Item synced" + local_items.length)
      localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(local_items))
    } else {
      dismissToast()
      errorToast("Error syncing items")
      localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(local_items))
      return
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    dismissToast()
    errorToast("Error syncing items")
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(local_items))
    return
  })
}
}
```

the alert shows up for all items but the countdown gets stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local_items.splice(i, 1)` is not a good way to remove the elements, it will only work for the first half elements and not work for the rest.

Try `local_items.shift()` instead.